# javascript (DOJO) file caching - Client side

Tags: javascript, dojo, cache-control

I want to implement caching of the javascript files (Dojo Tool kit) which are not going to change.. Currently my home page takes about 15-17 secs to load and upon refresh it takes 5-6 secs on load.. But is there a way to use the cached files again when we load it in a new browser session.. I do not want the browser to make request to the server on load of the application home page in a new browser session? Also is there a option to set the expiry to a certain number of days.. I tried with META tag and not helping much.. Either I'm doing something wrong or I'm not implementing it correctly..

I have implemented the dojo compression tool kit and see a slight improvement in the performance but not significant..

Answer (score 0):

Usually your browser should do that already anyway. Please check if caching is really turned on and not only for session.

However, creating a custom dojo build with your app profile defining layers with dojo the build puts all your code together and bundles it with dojo.js (the files are still available independently). The result is just one http request for all of the code (larger file but just once). The gained speed due to reduced http requests is much more than a cache could ever provide.

For details refer to the tutorial: http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.8/build/

Answer (score 0):

The caching is made by the browser, which behaviour is influenced by **Cache-Control** HTTP header (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html). Normally, the browser would ask, if newer version of resources is available, so you get 1 short request for each resource anyway.

From my experience, even with very aggresive caching, when the browser is instructed not to ask for the version of the resource on server for the given period of time, the checking in the browser cache for such an immense number of resources is a costly process.

The real solution are **custom builds**. You have written something about "dojo compression", I assume you're acquainted with the [Dojo build profiles](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/build/profiles.html). It's quite nasty documented, but once you're successfull with it, you should have some big file(s) with layer(s), with the following format:

```
require({cache:{
    "name/of/dojo/resource": function() { ... here comes the content of JS file ... }
    , ...
}});
```

It's a multi-definition file that inlines all definitions of modules within single layer. So, loading such file will load many modules in **single request**. But you must **load** the layer.

In order to get layers to run I've had to add the extra require to each of my entry JS files (those that are referenced in the headers of HTML file):

```
require(["dojo/domReady!"], function(){
// load the layers
require(['dojo/dojo-qm',/*'qmrzsv/qm'*/], function(){

  // here is your normal dojo code, all modules will be loaded from the memory cache
  require(["dojo", "dojo/on", "dojo/dom-attr", "dojo/dom-class"...], 
  function(dojo,on,domAttr,domClass...){
    ....
  })
})
})
```

It has significantly improved the performance. The bottleneck was loading a large amount of little javascript modules, not parsing them. Loading and parsing all modules at once is much cheaper that loading hundreds of them on demand.